# Proving that $\sum{|a_n+b_n|^p}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces

I'm trying to prove that $\ell^p$, $p\in\mathbb{N}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ where $\mathbb{K}$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. But I don't really see how to proceed with the closure under addition.
The definition I'm using for $\ell^p$ is
\begin{equation}
 \ell^p = \left\{\left\{a_n\right\}\in\mathbb{K}^\mathbb{N}\ \middle|\ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |a_n|^p <\infty\right\}
\end{equation}
Suppose that for some fixed $p$, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|^p$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty|b_n|^p$ converge.
How does it imply that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{|a_n+b_n|^p}$ converges?

Any help is gladly appreciated.

*Edit:*
I tried the following:
\begin{align}
\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty{|a_n+b_n|^p} &= \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(|a_n|^p + |b_n|^p +\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{p \choose k}|a_n|^{p-k}|b_n|^{k}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{|a_n|^p}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty{|b_n|^p}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{p \choose k}|a_n|^{p-k}|b_n|^{k}
\end{align}
But I still find it hard to see how to proceed.

Comment: What is $p{}{}{}$?

Comment: Added it to the question.

Comment: Have you done the case $p=2$? Start there. (Of course, the $p=1$ case is not worth mentioning.)

Comment: Yup, For that case I used Cauchy Schwarz inequality

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for any $n$ you have

$\vert a_n + b_n \vert^p \leq (\vert a_n\vert +\vert b_n\vert) ^p \leq (2\max \{\vert a_n\vert, \vert b_n\vert\})^p  =  2^p\max \{\vert a_n\vert^p,\vert b_n \vert^p\} \leq 2^p (\vert a_n\vert^p+\vert b_n \vert^p)$,

so you get convergence from the direct comparison test.